# How can I get my Web application to communicate with my Desktop application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a Web and windows application, both in C#.NET. Now, what I would like to do is when a button is clicked on a particular page in the web application, a signal has to be sent to the windows app saying a link has been clicked. How could I do this really easily? I would like to stay away from socket programming...

I thought of the web app storing cookies and the desktop application monitoring the cookies folder but that seems a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop app could poll the web app via normal http, but having an open connection would probably be better. You could also use something like .NET remoting or WCF to enable a IPC sort of communication.

You could also check out Named Pipes for IPC.

Answer (score 3):

A simple web service should do the trick.  Just create a service in ASP.NET and add it as a reference to your desktop application.  There's no need to go overkill to accomplish such a simple task.

You could use WCF or Remoting or Sockets -- by why waste time when the learning curve is so much higher?  Creating a web service will take no time at all and should give you all the functionality you need.

Here's a brief walkthrough to get you up and running.

1. In Visual Studio, create a new web site and select ASP.NET Web Service.
2. A stub method will be created called HelloWorld e.g.

   [WebMethod]

   public string HelloWorld() {

   ```
   return "Hello World";
   ```

   }
3. Run your site.
4. Go to your desktop application.
5. Under your solution explorer, right click on the project and click Add Web Reference
6. Enter the URL of where you have your web service running and click Go**
7. Once your reference is found, rename it to something meaningful and click Add Reference.
8. You can now access the methods exposed by your web service as if they are local objects.  You should be able to now see the HelloWorld method exposed by the service.

** Remember, in order for you to have a web reference with a static URL, you'll need to host the reference in IIS.  When Visual Studio runs your service from the IDE, it will create a temporary URL and port, which WILL change on future runs.  This is simply to show you how simple working with web services are.

You can add your own methods and return types in the same class as the HelloWorld method, by adding the [WebMethod] flag above your methods.  If you change something in your service, go back to your desktop application, right click on the service, and click Update.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me a bit more detail on how I could achieve this with a web service? Certainly sounds like an attractive idea...

Answer (score 1):

Probably equally clumsy as the cookies idea, but the web app could store information about the link that was clicked (when, by who, values of controls on the page, etc.) and store it in a database which the client application periodically polls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .NET remoting for such kind of tasks. That would mean that the Desktop client must start a .NET remoting server so that the Webserver can call methods of the Desktop client.

But this may impose security risks. Additionally, routers or firewalls may block access to the clients. Maybe it is better to use polling, that is the desktop client queries the server periodically for new events. For that, a simple REST-API would suffice, although .NET remoting could be used here also (as well as SOAP or CORBA).

Answer (score 0):

Have your windows application harbour a self-hosted web service and call this web service from your web app whenever the user clicks the button. See e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wcf+self-hosted+web+service) on how to do this. It's really easy and the way to go, imho.

(You don't want sockets... Well, there are sockets buried deep in this solution, but then there are in all the solutions suggested so far, a part from named pipes and shared files but those both have serious disatvantages. Anyway, you won't be bothered by these sockets, they are taken care of by the framework, no worries.)

Answer (score 0):

As always, there's more than one way to skin the cat. Here are my take on it.

**if you don't need instantaneous response but require the scalability to support alot of desktop clients**

the click can simply manifest itself as an event in a "command bus" (read: [event aggregator](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126051618/https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)). The items within the command bus is exposed through a web service.
the desktop app then can simply "observe" the command bus by polling the web service if there's a new 'command' that it hasn't seen before.

Potentially using [Reactive Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29) for .Net can help here. The web exposes IObservable and the desktop client becomes the IObserver

**if you need a more instantaneous response, but will only have limited number of desktop clients, and each client have permanent IP Addresses**

host wcf service in the desktop client. Bind this using net tcp against your public ip address (for e.g net.tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8523/Service1). When a user clicks a button on the website, the website will then send a request to the wcf service which is hosted within your desktop client. the details of this is pretty blurry to me, but seems like a logical approach.

**if you need a more instantaneous response, but will only have limited number of desktop clients, and each client do not have permanent IP Addresses, and willing to pay for cloud service**
Here's where a Azure Service Bus might come in handy. Everytime a user clicks on a link, a message gets pushed to the Azure Service Bus. Each of the desktop client can subscribe to events in the Azure Service Bus. Here's an example [Azure service](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104052243/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2010/01/03/azure-service-bus-eventing-in-the-app-fabric-project-weather-cloud-creating-the-weather-stations.aspx)